# How do I get a Verified SSL Certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, web, certificate, server

I been trying to make my own website in IIS. but I need a verified SSL Certificate for my website. I don't want to use self-signed certificate. Can we get a SSL Certificate for free? or paid?

Answer (score 0):

SSL Certificates must be purchased from a verified Root Certificate Authority. There used to be one which gave them for free, but that no longer exists. Companies such as VeriSign, GoDaddy, and Symantec can sell you certificates. They cost around £75 per year.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an one year free Certificate from https://www.startssl.org/.
This is not an trial offer an can be renewed each year. It is only valid for domain and www.domain.

Comment: Find another free CA:
http://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/41289/free-chinese-2-year-ssl-certificate-dv-kuaissl-by-wosign-com